# Раскрыть скобки (a+b)%c

Tags: математика, логика

Можно ли преобразовать (a+b)%c к сумме слагаемых, каждое из которых не содержит a и b одновременно?

Comment: (a%c + b%c)%c подойдет?

Comment: боюсь, что нет, a и b в одной скобке

Comment: @McFinley вам стоит отредактировать формулировку вопроса. Сейчас там говорится про то, что единственный плохой вариант - если в **каждом** из слагаемых есть и `a`, и `b`. То есть, например, `a*b + a*b*d` - это плохо, а `a + b` или `a*b + b` - вполне нормально.

Comment: Как мне тогда лучше сформулировать требование к решению: единственный хороший вариант - когда все слагаемые не содержат a и b одновременно?

Comment: Возможно вам стоит переписать условие в виде `(a+b)%c = x` и выдвинуть требование, чтобы `a` и `b` в ответе были по разные стороны знака равенства?

Comment: @McFinley, т.е. вариант вида ((a-1)%c + (b-1)%c + 2)%c вас тоже не устраивает? Тогда, боюсь, у вас ничего не получится, т.к. каждое из чисел может быть меньше c, но при этом сумма этих двух чисел уже будет больше либо равно c (например, если a = b = c - 1, при c > 2). Можно заменить взятие остатка другой операцией, но сути это не изменит. Может вы распишите зачем вам это? Если боитесь переполнения при сложении, то при `c` меньшем MAX_INT / 2 никакого переполнения не будет.

Comment: На самом деле мне нужно выразить i-тый бит суммы чисел (a+b). Я решил, что i-тый бит числа это [a/2^i]%2, где [x] - целая часть числа x, и теперь необходимо выразить i-тый бит суммы, т.е. [(a+b)/2^i]%2. Пытаясь сделать это я пришел к задаче поменьше, выдвинутой в вопросе. В кратце: мне нужно узнать чему равно [a+b], где [x] - целая часть числа, a и b > 0

Comment: [a+b] = x, где a и b по разные стороны знака равенства :)

Comment: Что такое `%` в данном случае? О каком ответе на этот вопрос вообще может идти речь, если приведена какая-то бессмысленная формула с каким-то загадочными символами внутри?

Answer (score 4):

Можно раскрыть следующим образом

```
(a + b)%c = (a%c + b%c)%c
```

Comment: А как внешнее (находящееся за скобками) `%c` в правой части равенства вяжется с дистрибутивностью?

Comment: @Regent, хороший вопрос. Я найду литературу с правильным определением дистрибутивности и за одно докажу дистрибутивность деления по модулю, как только появится время.

Comment: Сильно же вы загружены :)

Comment: @Regent, я помню. Вернусь к этому.

Comment: это точно не сумма)

Comment: Вы все еще загружены?...

Comment: @Mikhailo да, я, скорее всего, к этому не вернусь. Прошу прощения за неудобство. Поменял ответ, чтобы не вызывал вопросов.

Answer (score 1):

Можно в случае `a + b < c`тогда подходят `a` и `b` по отдельности.
Иначе - нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

> На самом деле мне нужно выразить i-тый бит суммы чисел (a+b).

```
((a+b)>>i)&1

((a+b)/pow(2,i))%2
```